# jQuery style class not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why is my jQuery code not increasing the font size?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      a.test { font-size:40px; }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a").addClass("test");
      });
    </script>

    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I write the style class within element `a` the font size increases, but not when I write it using jQuery. Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/VaJ3b/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use both a `src` value on a `<script>` tag and put scripts in it like you've done.  Use a separate script tag for your code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("a").addClass("test");
 });
</script>
```

When done right, you can see that the code works here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ndvDs/

Answer (score 6):

You cannot add JS code inside a script tag that has a src attribute. Instead, close that script tag immediately and start a new one for the code to be run.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the

```
       $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a").addClass("test");
         });
```

into a script of it's own.

so you end up with:

```
      <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
```

and

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a").addClass("test");
         });
      </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the code to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("a").addClass("test");
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").addClass("test");
});
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js">

$(document).ready(function(){
         $("a").addClass("test");
     });

 </script>
```

To somthing more like:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){ // this is like window.onload = function(){...
            $("a").addClass("test");
        })
    </script>
```